# Return a backbone model if the model contains a key that exists using findWhere

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to use findWhere to find out if a collection has a model that contains a specific key (which if it exists will be an object).  I only want to know if the collection contains this criteria.

Here is a sample collection:

```
var collection = new Backbone.Collection([
  {name: "Tim", age: 5},
  {name: "Ida", age: 26, schools: {elementary: "School One", middle_school: "School Two"} },
  {name: "Rob", age: 55}
]);
```

How would I determine if this collection has a model that has the key `schools` with findWhere?  Is there a faster way of determining this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`findWhere()` doesn't work like that. I'd use `find()` or `some()`:

```js
collection.find(function (model) {
  return model.has('schools');
});
```

It will return the first model that passes the test (or `undefined`). If you don't care about the model you can just test the return value for truthiness, or you can use `some()` instead:

```js
collection.some(function (model) {
  return model.has('schools');
});
```

It'll return `true` if a model passes the test. Of course they don't document what it returns if nothing passes the test.

See the documentation on [Collection : Underscore Methods](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods) for more info.

Comment: Your second example is exactly what I was looking for.  So simple, thanks!